# Fancybox "The requested content cannot be loaded"

Tags: fancybox

```
<div class="img">
    <a href="images/foto4.jpg">
        <img src="images/foto4.jpg" width="140" height="100" class="foto">
    </a>
</div>

<script>
(function(){
    $('.foto').fancybox();
})
</script>
```

I have installed everything as in the tutorial, but when I click on the picture I get

> The requested content cannot be loaded.
>   Please try again later.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are those spaces (like `< script`) really in your code? If so, that's likely to break all kinds of stuff.

Comment: Also, you don't have anything in the code above with an id of `foto`, so the line `$('#foto').fancybox();` is guaranteed to have problems.

Comment: spaces are not in the code, same thing without    $('#foto').fancybox(); line

Comment: I've tried to clean up your post. Please make sure the above reflects the code that you are using.

Comment: Ok, now its exactly the same

Comment: I'm not a fancybox expert, but I think you have to attach the fancybox to the link, not the image, so this will fix it. Add `class="image_link"` to your `<a>` tag and replace `$('.foto').fancybox();` with `$('.image_link').fancybox();`. If that works, let me know and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Ok, I've decided to use lightbox instead, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work but not perfect here your class should be in a `tag`

```
<a href="images/foto4.jpg" class="foto">  <!--class foo added in here-->
        <img src="images/foto4.jpg" width="140" height="100"> <!--class foo removed-->
</a>
```

Now if you still facing this problem check your image when it popup. Is it get directory correctly or not ? Better you can check it keep the image without any folder.

Note : Here fancy popup will show your `a href` image.

For details see the [example](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)